# Siege [error] socket: connection timed out

Tags: apache, sockets, apache2, benchmarking, siege

I am developing a specific web application firewall which I am benchmarking to see the performance degradation when the firewall is enabled. 
I am using `siege -c3 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` but I get after 400 requests this error:

```
[error] socket: -1311799552 connection timed out.: Connection timed out
[error] socket: -1303406848 connection timed out.: Connection timed out
[error] socket: -1295014144 connection timed out.: Connection timed out
```

Notice I use only 3 concurrent connections, so I am wondering why the socket is timing out...
I am using a default apache configuration. I have not installed mod_evasion explicitly. 
I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: I get this same issue on nginx. Check the logs on your server, php, or any other services that may be involved